# Heat capacity at constant volume and Gibbs free energy

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, free-energy

I want to know if it is possible to derive heat capacities, in this case, in constant volume from another thermodynamic Potential which is not the  Helmholtz free energy $F$. I am aware of the following relationship between heat capacity at constant volume, entropy, and $F$:
$$
C_v
  = T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N}
  = -T \left(\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial T^2}\right)_{V,N}.
$$

But I am trying to see if I can derive an expression for $C_v$ when I consider the Gibbs free energy (particle number constant $N$) and I want to express $C_v = C_v(T,P,n)$ where $n$ is taken as a constant and can be left out:
$$G = U - TS + PV = F + PV $$

The problem I have going forwards has to do with the variables. This is what I mean:
\begin{align}
  C_v &=
    -T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N} =
    -T\left(\frac{\partial^2 (G-PV)}{\partial T^2}\right)_{V,N}\\
  C_v &=
    -T\left[\left(\frac {\partial^2 G}{\partial T^2}\right)_{V,N} 
    -\left(\frac{\partial^2 PV}{\partial T^2}\right)_{V,N}\right]\\
  C_v &= 
    -T\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial T}
      \left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_{P,N}\right]_{V,N} 
    -T\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial T}
      \left(\frac{\partial PV}{\partial T}\right)\right]_{V,N}
\end{align}

Then, I use the following relation:
$$
  \left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N} =
  -\left(\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial P \partial T}\right)
   \left(\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial p^2}\right)^{-1},
$$
which gives me
$$
  C_v = 
  -T\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial T}
    \left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial T}\right)_{P,N}\right]_{V,N} 
  -T\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial T}
    \left(-V
      \left(\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial P \partial T}\right)
      \left(\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial p^2}\right)^{-1}
    \right)\right]_{V,N}
$$

And this is as far as I can get. Here is the problem. If we focus on the first term and do the derivations, I get:
$$
-T\left(\frac{\partial(-S)}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N}
$$
Now I don't know what to do. The entropy was derived by focusing on the Gibbs equation, and now if I want to go further, I have to look at the entropy for the internal energy. But there is nothing I can do. All I can say is that the above term can be equal to:
$$
C_v = T\left(\frac{\partial(-S)}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N},
$$
where this $C_v$ has nothing to do with the one in the beginning. My problem is with the 2nd term. I don't know what to do there because $G$ is a function of $T$, $N$, $P$, and we also have $V$, $N$. If I were to write it explicitly, this is what I cannot solve:
$$\begin{multline}
  \left[
    \frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left(
      -V(\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial P \partial T}
    \right)\left(
      \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial p^2}
    \right)^{-1}
  \right]_{V,N} 
  \\ = %split here
  \frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left(
    -V\left(
      \frac{\partial}{\partial P}\left(
        \left(
          \frac{\partial G}{\partial T}
        \right)_{P,N}
      \right)_{T,N}
    \right)_{V,N}\left(
      \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial p^2}
    \right)^{-1}_{V,N}
  \right)
\end{multline}$$

This term:
$$
  \frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left(
    -V\left(
      \frac{\partial}{\partial P}\left(
        \left(
          \frac{\partial G}{\partial T}
        \right)_{P,N}
      \right)_{T,N}
    \right)_{V,N}
  \right)
$$

How do I try and solve this? The indexes confuse me. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! On Chemistry mathematical and chemical expressions can be formatted using MathJax (and LaTeX Syntax).  If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). We prefer to not use MathJax in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details. There were a couple of parenthesis/brackets missing and I) hope I didn't put them in all the wrong places. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for can be trivially obtained by referring to the well known general relation between constant-volume and constant-pressure heat capacity:
$$
C_v= C_p -\frac{\alpha^2TV}{\chi_T}.
$$
In this formula, present in almost all textbooks on thermodynamics and easily derivable by using Maxwell's relations and some partial derivative manipulation, all the quantities on the right-hand side of the equation can be represented as derivatives of the Gibbs free energy and the independent variable $T$:
$$
\begin{align}
V &= \left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial p}\right)_{T,n};\\
C_p &= T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{p,n}=-T\left(\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial T^2}\right)_{p,n};\\
\alpha &=\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial T}\right)_{p,n}=
\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial T\partial p}\right);\\
\chi_T&=-\frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}\right)_{T,n}= -\left(\frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial p^2}\right)_{T,n}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @Poutnik Actually, in my case,  It was simply a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. I am going to correct it.